# Getting "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher" error

Tags: python, oracle11g, pycharm

I am trying to use **pycharm(3.3)**  to access my **Oracle SQL(11.2.0)** using the below codes but getting error with below details.

**Code used:**

```
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('uname/pwd@14@server')
```

**Error received**

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue very similar to yours. I was able to solve it by using a different connection method:

```
my_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("host",port,sid="sid")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password", dsn=my_dsn)
cursor = connection.cursor()

querystring = "SQL query"
cursor.execute(querystring)
```

See http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html for more information