# connect oracle 10g databse in python error

Tags: python, database, oracle, oracle10g

how to connect oracle 10g database in python?

I have tried with

```
import cx_Oracle and then 
connection= cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@localhost')
```

but it gives error

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at
>   version 11.2 or higher

how to solve this error?
or is it possible to install lower version of cx_Oracle i have tried but still gives error

> cannot locate an Oracle software installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "cx\_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450646/getting-cx-oracle-databaseerror-dpi-1050-oracle-client-library-must-be-at-ver)

Comment: tried this but still getting the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cx_oracle documentation [clearly states which versions of the Oracle client are supported](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#overview). As the error message indicates the oldest supported version is 11.2.

You have an Oracle 10g database, which is at least two major versions older than 11gR2. The chances are your client is 10g too. Hence the error. You can try downloading a more recent version of the client; Oracle have fairly good backwards compatibility between client and server so you should be okay. [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html).

However, you are working with a version of the database which has been deprecated for many years. The price of not upgrading your software is debugging of gnarly integration issues.

Comment: versions over oracle 10g don' t have support for linux having 32-bit architecture and my machine have 32-bit so that's why i installed 10g.

Comment: it's easy for me to say, just upgrade your machine. So that is what I 'm going to say. Because I don't have a better answer, alas