# Python and Oracle DB - "Error DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher"

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

Some days ago, I was asked to develop a Python application capable of connecting to a Oracle DB. Since I already have an Oracle client installed (version 12.2.0), I just pip installed cx_Oracle and tried to establish a connection using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@service_as_described_in_tnsnames.ora')
cur=connection.cursor()

input("Press Enter to continue...")

cur.execute('select* from MY_PRETTY_TABLE')
for line in cur:
    print()

cur.close()
connection.close()
```

But when trying to run it, I got the error "**DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher**". After googling it, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450646/getting-cx-oracle-databaseerror-dpi-1050-oracle-client-library-must-be-at-ver) answer, and tried to change my code to:

```
my_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("host",port,sid="sid")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password", dsn=my_dsn)
cursor = connection.cursor()

querystring = "SQL query"
cursor.execute(querystring)
```

But still, same error. It's important to notice that I have already used Oracle DB client in this same machine, to connect a DB with Power BI.

Also, if it can be helpful, my paths are setted as:

```
C:\instantclient_12_1
C:\Users\oracle2\product\12.1.0\client_1
C:\Users\oracle2\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin
C:\Users\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin
```

Comment: `PATH` can be set to anything, even non-existent directories. It does not help to provide an incomplete list of what's on `PATH`. What's important is what's *in* the directories on `PATH`. Furthermore, we have no guarantee that Power BI is even using the same Oracle client. There could be other factors affecting which version it finds.

Comment: Furthermore, contrary to all the instructions you'll find everywhere, placing Oracle client on `PATH` permanently is nothing but a large headache. I and my coworkers have worked with the native Oracle client *a lot* for several years, and globally modifying `PATH` has created more problems than it solved. You'll be *far* better off coding your application to find the client itself, such as by prepending `PATH` explicitly with the location of a bundled client when the process launches or ensuring that bundled client is otherwise loaded at runtime. Make sure you handle 32/64 bitness.

Comment: Oh, good to know. But sincerely, I really don't know why my question was downvoted, just because I didn't know something...

Comment: The downvote was mine. It was given for the reasons I discuss at more length [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373559/1394393). The short version is that fixing this basically requires an interactive debugging session, which is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @jpmc26 FWIW, the future ODPI-C 3 (and hence cx_Oracle 7) on Windows (only) will [look first for Oracle Client libraries in the same directory as the ODPI-C or cx_Oracle binary is located it](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/commit/d02192a77783523f2e74aa6518241a8fc58b9616).  This may help some install scenarios, particularly for people creating software bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error implies that you have *another* older version of the Oracle client installed somewhere earlier in your PATH. You should do a search for OCI.DLL on your machine (using where.exe or the dir command) and either move or remove any unnecessary copies or adjust PATH as needed. Some older applications stuffed OCI.DLL in C:\Windows\System32 improperly, for example.

Comment: Don't do searches for files unless necessary. Use `where.exe` to figure out what is on `PATH` to be found on Windows (`which` on Linux).

Comment: Is where.exe a standard part of Windows? If not, your suggestion won't help...and neither will downvoting my suggestion!

Comment: Yes, it is built in. Furthermore, deleting files upon which other applications may depend is dangerous as well.

Comment: It's also not guaranteed that there's an older version installed.

Comment: Okay, so I used the **where.exe** suggestion you gave. I got three paths: 

C:\Users\oracle2\product\12.1.0\client_1\oci.dll;


C:\Users\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll;


C:\Windows\System32\oci.dll

Comment: The one in c:\Windows\System32 is very likely the old one. You can check its version information and either delete it or move it somewhere else. It should never have been put there in the first place, but some applications did that as a convenience. If you still require the application that did that, then you're stuck, unfortunately.

Comment: Anthony Tuininga is the main cx_oracle developer employed by Oracle I believe.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga, you were right, indeed! The version in my system32 is the wrong one. Since I couldn't delete it, I just renamed it and is now working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: @PedroMartins Renaming it is just as harmful as deleting it.

Comment: @jpmc26, it can be, but frequently isn't. The application may already have been removed (it frequently is) but it doesn't clean up this DLL. And Windows often loads all DLLs found in this directory (or perhaps registered in the registry) so you have to rename it, then reboot, then you can delete it. There is no other way to clean up this mess. Of course this presumes that the application that did this is long gone. If it is still there, it will begin failing, of course.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Yes, that's the point. If you rename it, then other applications will not be able to find it. That is the harm of deleting it as well. The end result is the same: you break anything that depends on it being there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem had to do with Oracle Instant client Version 19.3.0.0.0.
I uninstalled it and installed the previous version Oracle Instant client 12.2.0.1.0 to and it worked.
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

Important things to do before you try above:

From Windows command prompt

```
c:> where oci.dll
```

make sure you find only one entry and remove the redundant ones.

Ensure you set the environment path to the newly installed client.