# Connecting Python 3.x to Oracle DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyodbc, cx-oracle

I am unable to connect to our enterprise Oracle Db using python 3/cx_Oracle.

Installed are:

```
    python 3 -32 bit
    cx_Oracle
    Oracle Client 12.1.0.2.0
```

My connection string attempt is:

```
    import cx_Oracle
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='user', password='pwd', dsn='working_dsn')
```

My PATH variable includes the direct path to my working Oracle library (works using SQL Dev

Error message is:

```
     cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 0.0 but must be at version 11.2 or higher
```

I have researched the Orcale installation instructions and have found no way to connect.  I have previously tried with no success, had my computer reimaged and Oracle reinstalled to ensure only one version of Oracle and still no success.  I need to move from R to Python and this is the last piece I need to make the switch.  I am able to connect with R using JDBC driverclass/dbConnect.

If cx_Oracle wont work, is there another option for connecting to Oracle from Python3?

Any thoughts suggestions or places to look?  Other connection types used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure yet, is this related? [Getting “cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450646/getting-cx-oracle-databaseerror-dpi-1050-oracle-client-library-must-be-at-ver)

Comment: I just tried this....for the same error

Comment: What platform, are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes sorry, should have said that initially

Comment: have you also compared to other simliar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=windows%20cx_Oracle.DatabaseError%3a%20DPI-1050 I see 2. Sorry I'm not on windows to reproduce that error.

Comment: Yes I reviewed quite a few and tried the solutions without success.  Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install cx_Oracle

first method：

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('root/root@localhost: 1523/orcl')
```

Second method：

```
db = cx_Oracle.connect('root/root@localhost: 1523/orcl')
```

Third method

```
makedsn(IP/HOST, PORT, TNSNAME)
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost','1523','orcl')
db = cx_Oracle.connect('root','root',dsn)
```

Comment: pip3  install cx_Oracle==5.3

Comment: interesting.  I do this and i get the following error:                                                            Oracle home (C:\oracle64\instantclient-basiclite-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip\instantclient_12_2) does not refer to an 10g, 11g or 12c installation.  Does this mean i need to download a different version of Oracle?

Comment: Are you sure your oracle client version is compatible?

Comment: Is your python 32 bit or 64 bit? The python version should be 3.6 or 2.7.

Comment: I am using anaconda python 3.7 32 bit

Comment: use python 3.6 ,Python3.7 has a number of compatibility problems

Comment: cx_Oracle 5.3 and python 3.6 is ok

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I uninstalled anaconda and installed pure python 3.6.7 (32 bit) When I try to pop install cx_Oracle==5.3 I get an error that I need MS Visual C++ 14 but that is no longer available from MS.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting suggests that you have an older version of the Oracle client installed on your machine. Search the directories of your PATH environment variable for OCI.DLL. If you find an older version you'll need to remove or rename it -- just be aware that whatever application put the file there will stop working!

Another possibility is to go to a command prompt and do the following

```
PATH=my_path_to_instant_client;%PATH%
python test_connect.py
```

Finally, make sure that if your Python is 32-bit, so is your instant client installation, and if your Python is 64-bit, make sure that your instant client installation is also 64-bit.

Comment: I tried this and no success.  Which version of instantclient  is best?  Maybe I can try to reinstall

Comment: It shouldn't matter which version of the instant client -- as it long as it is the right bits (32 or 64) and is at least 11.2.